# Getting a list of elements contained in a ul TestObject in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

I have saved a TestObject in Katalon, which has a ul tag. I wish to use that to write a test case that involves its li elements, but don't know how to select, let alone loop through, them in Katalon. In Selenium WebDriver, it would be something like `driver.findElements(By.css("#myUlElement li"))` followed by something like an enhanced for loop.

How to do this in Katalon?

Answer (score 5):

1. Assumed that your Test Object(named: **listItem**) has the XPath like below :

   `//*[@id="myUlElement"]/li`
2. On your test case/ keyword, to get the list of **li** web element, use below:

   `List<WebElement> listElement = WebUI.findWebElements(findTestObject("listItem"),2)`

See more about findWebElements [here](https://api-docs.katalon.com/studio/v4.5.0/api/com.kms.katalon.core.webui/com/kms/katalon/core/webui/keyword/WebUiBuiltInKeywords.html#findWebElements(com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject,%20int)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the answer. I found out you could bring in the `WebDriver` like this: `WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver()`. That would allow for Selenium-specific code within Katalon script